# Passed object as intent(inout) in a type-bound elemental procedure

Tags: fortran, parameter-passing, type-bounds

I want to add text to a scalar object's component no matter what is shape of this additional text.

To try this, I create an elemental procedure that has a elemental input argument but only one `intent(inout)` argument which is the passed object.

Here is a MWE:

```
module add_mod
  implicit none

  type obj_A
    character(len=:), allocatable    :: Message
  contains
    procedure, pass(objA) :: add
    procedure, pass(objA) :: write
  end type

contains
   elemental subroutine add( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(inout)                   :: objA
      character(len=*), intent(in)                 :: text

      objA%Message=objA%Message//text
   end subroutine add

    impure elemental subroutine write( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(in)                   :: objA
      character(len=*), intent(in)                 :: text

      print*,'write ', text
   end subroutine write
end module


program test
  use add_mod
  implicit none

  type(obj_A) :: testA


  call testA%add('toto')
  print *, testA%Message

  ! call testA%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )
  print *, testA%Message

  call testA%write( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )

end program
```

If I let commented the line `call testA%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )`, it works fine. But if I uncomment, I have an error during the compilation

> Error: Actual argument at (1) for INTENT(INOUT) dummy 'objA' of ELEMENTAL subroutine 'add' is a scalar, but another actual argument is an array`

I understand why it is correct with the `testA%write` call, it is due to the `intent(in)` of the passed object; in this case the compiler understands that one argument is scalar shape and the other one is array shape.

With the `testA%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )`, I also understand that it requires an array shaped `obj_A` as `intent(inout)`, since the text given for input is a scalar. Thus, it is not the correct way to do it.

Is there a correct way to add text to `obj_A%Message` no matter what is shape of this text?

Comment: I would like to add a text to the Message contained in obj_A without carrying about the shape of this text. The only solution that I saw is the use of generic procedure, but I would like to avoid the solution.

Comment: I do not see a way to avoid generic procedures if you want to process both scalar and vector arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `elemental` subroutines, you can provide an array input and an *array* output [the operations then occur in an element-wise way]. However, you are trying to assign an array input to a scalar output (here: `testA`).

If you used an array output of size 3, your routine works as expected:

```
module add_mod
  implicit none

  type obj_A
    character(len=:), allocatable    :: Message
  contains
    procedure, pass(objA) :: add
  end type

contains
   elemental subroutine add( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(inout)                   :: objA
      character(len=*),intent(in)                   :: text

      objA%Message=objA%Message//text
   end subroutine add
end module

program test
  use add_mod
  implicit none

  type(obj_A) :: testA
  type(obj_A) :: testB(3)

  call testA%add('toto')
  print *, testA%Message

  call testB%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )
  print *, testA%Message
  print *, testB(1)%Message, testB(2)%Message, testB(3)%Message
end program
```

Here is a version to add an array of strings to a scalar output. Please note that due this constellation, the subroutine cannot be `elemental`. However, it can be `pure`:

```
module add_mod
  implicit none

  type obj_A
    character(len=:), allocatable    :: Message
  contains
    procedure, pass(objA) :: add
  end type

contains
   pure subroutine add( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(inout)                   :: objA
      character(len=*), dimension(:), intent(in)    :: text
      integer :: i

      do i=1,size(text)
        objA%Message=objA%Message//text(i)
      enddo !i
   end subroutine add
end module

program test
  use add_mod
  implicit none

  type(obj_A) :: testA

  call testA%add(['toto'])
  print *, testA%Message

  call testA%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )
  print *, testA%Message
end program
```

Finally, to support both scalar and array arguments, you need to provide and bind several implementations and then use a `generic` interface to provide them under the same name:

```
module add_mod
  implicit none

  type obj_A
    character(len=:), allocatable    :: Message
  contains
    generic :: add => add1, add2
    procedure, pass(objA) :: add1
    procedure, pass(objA) :: add2
  end type

contains
   pure subroutine add1( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(inout)                   :: objA
      character(len=*), dimension(:), intent(in)    :: text
      integer :: i

      do i=1,size(text)
        objA%Message=objA%Message//text(i)
      enddo 
   end subroutine add1

   pure subroutine add2( objA, text )
      implicit none

      class(obj_A), intent(inout)                   :: objA
      character(len=*), intent(in)                  :: text

      objA%Message=objA%Message//text
   end subroutine add2
end module

program test
  use add_mod
  implicit none

  type(obj_A) :: testA

  call testA%add('toto')
  print *, testA%Message

  call testA%add( ['toto','abcc','d,ef'] )
  print *, testA%Message
end program
```